# eloquent ORM save entity in two schemas

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

Is it possible to save an eloquent ORM entity in more than one schema ?

for exemple, can I define this in a model :

```
protected $connection = ['first', 'second'];
```

then when i save a model it will save to the connections listed ?

Comment: take a look [here](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections) i think it will help you !

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't set `$connection` as an array, this is only meant to specify the default connection for the model if it is different from the app's default connection (or you just want to be explicit).

If you want to use different connections you can:

```
Model::connection('first')->update([]);

Model::connection('second')->update([]);
```

Depending on your version you might need to use `on()` instead of `connection()` with eloquent:

```
Model::on('first')->update([]);
```

Hope this helps!